# Converting C code into 8086 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, emu8086

Is there any direct way to convert *C* code into emu8086 assembly?

Comment: You an either write a compiler or translate it by hand. The later is probably the easier option unless you have a lot of C code to translate.

Comment: That's *exactly* what a compiler does.

Comment: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html

Comment: I read it the other way around! And I thought, why would someone want that?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the bcc compiler (Bruce's *C* compiler). It will output 8086 assembly. The manpage is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bcc). There are Fedora/Ubuntu/Arch packages available. I'm not sure about Microsoft Windows options.